# Using API to retrieve contact records by modified date

Tags: api

I basically have the same questions as described in these topics https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=22774.0
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=24121.0

I would like to know which parameter to use in an api call url to get the last modified date in the list of returned fields

and

which parameter to add to an api call url so that it only returns the contacts that where created/modified since a specific date (or if this isn't possible: the parameter for all contacts created since a specific date, and the parameter to get all contacts modified since a specific date).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `modified_date` in `Contact.get` eg:

Return the date:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => array("modified_date"),
));
```

Search for Contacts modified after a date:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'modified_date' => array('>' => "2017-04-12"),
));
```

The API explorer is useful for exploring things like this.

Comment: 'The API explorer is useful for exploring things like this.' +1